# Make [judicial-branch] a tag synonym of [judiciary]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[judiciary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judiciary) has 17 questions, [judicial-branch](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judicial-branch) has 36 questions. They are basically the same, so it makes sense to make one the synonym of the other.

Comment: What's the process for retagging/burnination here? It's been a week with no downvotes or disagreement: are there certain positive criteria we should wait for before making the change (time, # upvotes)?

Comment: @divibisan not sure, though there have been only a few votes. We could ping in chat or something. Oh and those with enough rep in the tag can propose and vote manually, I think.

Comment: I see no reason not to move forward with this, but I don't have sufficient score in the tag to suggest a synonym

Comment: @divibisan same situation, I think this is one of these situations where executive power is needed. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole set of tags for the 3 typical branches of a government with separation of powers is a bit chaotic:

- There is no tag [executive](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/executive) but there is a tag [executive-branch](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/executive-branch) with 53 questions
- There is a tag [legislature](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislature) with 13 questions but no tag [legislative-branch](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-branch). There is also a tag [legislative-process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-process) with 89 questions with a couple questions which might be more about the branch itself than about its processes.
- The judicial branch has two competing tags with [judiciary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judiciary) with 17 questions and [judicial-branch](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judicial-branch) with 37 questions.

The separation of powers into 3 branches is AFAIK not specific to the United States but rather specific to most democratic republics (in fact the US isn't even the purest example, because the executive branch has some legislative power in form of the presidential veto). But on the other hand, there are also less democratic governments in the world which do not have a separation into distinct branches, but all governments have executive, legislative and judiciary functions.

So what I did is the following:

1. Made [judicial-branch](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judicial-branch) a synonym of [judiciary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judiciary)
2. Renamed [executive-branch](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/executive-branch) to [executive](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/executive)

Answer (score 4):

I agree that they should be synonyms, but wouldn't it be better the other way?

I've always though of "Judicial Branch" being specifically American, as a reference to the 3 branches of government. I've never heard it used for another country. Would you really talk about the Judicial Branch of the UK?

[judiciary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judiciary) is definitely [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Judicial+Branch%2C+Judiciary&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CJudicial%20Branch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CJudiciary%3B%2Cc0) and is definitely the more general and country-independent term.

Comment: Thanks, I removed that  part of my question (it hadn't been voted on much so I can get away with it). You make a convincing argument so I changed the title too.

Comment: "Would you really talk about the Judicial Branch of the UK?" No we wouldn't, because in the UK the judiciary and legislature are not regarded as branches of the government. Indeed, the official name of the executive here is "Her Majesty's Government" - and it refers _only_ to the executive.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff No, you’re right. That’s why I suggested that The US specific Judicial-branch be made a synonym of the more general Judiciary instead of the other way around

Comment: @divibisan: yup; I agree!